# Print option with page range not setting correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

```
PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
PrinterSettings.ToPage =2;
```

Whenever i send any range for ToPage as 2, when i check it always has its ToPage to 99, any thought?

```
PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
PrinterSettings.ToPage =2;
```

also when i debug, i see

?PageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrintRange 
SomePages {2}

instead of AllPages, so the printrange is setting the property for some pages, is there anything i need to set in order for the ToPage to reflect the user entered number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also set `PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages`